# How to get business object from SessionContext of a SFSB

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, openejb

I am not sure waht is the correct answer of below question.

> A developer writes a stateful session bean FooBean with two local
>   business interfaces Foo and bar. The developer wants to write a
>   business method called getBar for interface Foo that returns a Bar
>   reference to the same session bean identity on which the client
>   onvokes getBar. Which code, when inserted on line 12 below implements
>   the getBar method with the wanted behavior?

```
10. @Resource SessionContext sessionCtx;
11. public Bar getbar () {
12. ?????
13. }
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is [getBusinessObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html#getBusinessObject%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
return sessionCtx.getBusinessObject(Bar.class)
```